# Reference an equation in a different file with Sphinx

Tags: math, reference, python-sphinx

I am documenting my code using [Shinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/). In some files I have mathematical formulas and would like to include a reference to them. Being in the very same file this is not a problem. Using `:eq:'reference'`.

However, how do you cross reference to a formula from a different file? In my case [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) is unable to find the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Sphinx docs [here](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/math.html#role-eq), equation cross-referencing only works within the same document at present.  I suggest submitting a bug/feature request to get this changed (assuming there isn't one already).

As a workaround, you can probably use the [generic cross referencing syntax](http://sphinx-doc.org/markup/inline.html#cross-referencing-arbitrary-locations) by placing a reference label immediately before the equation you want to reference (in the "other" file), like so:

```
.. _equation_in_other_file:
```

and then use something like:

```
:ref:` Link Title <equation_in_other_file>`
```

in the "current" file to reference it.

(note you need to provide an explicit link title)

It's not quite as elegant, but it should get the job done.